# Statistics on three variables/factors

Tags: predictive-models, multiple-comparisons, model

I'm trying to say something about sales of candy bars. I got data on sales for a population of children. There are three factors: age, income of parents, and name of a child.

What I can compute from this data is, say, that 34% of all sold candy bars were bought by children of age 12, 25% by children of age 10, etc.

At the same time, I can compute that 52% were bought by children coming from families with monthly income X, 35% by children coming from families with monthly income Y, etc.

And finally, I know that say 40% of the bars were bought by Sams, 25% by Abigails, etc.

What I would like to deduce from these three characteristics is, given a child of certain age and name, and coming from a family with monthly income Z, what is the "probability" that he/she will buy a candy bar?

Comment: For these figures to be much use you're either need the data on the relative proportions in the population (what percentage of children are Sams, what percentage of children are from families with monthly income X, and so on - *as well as all these various things in combination*); alternatively, you need data on the percentages of each combination that *did not buy candy bars*.

Comment: Consider - if I tell you that of the $5 bills in my house, 25% are in my wallet and 10% are in my daughter's wallet, can you answer the question "what is the probability that a bill drawn from my daughter's wallet will be a 5?". The answer is *no*, you really can't - you'd need to know something about the bills that *aren't* fives.

Comment: @Glen_b, I believe I can compute these relationships that you mention. What I do have is a table that looks like: Name, Age, Income, Bought_Candy_Bar (Y/N). So, I could get more info from that on correlations/relations between the three "variables". Does that help solving my problem?

Comment: It does help, yes. It should be explicit in your question

Answer (score 2):

You can't deduce anything reliable about three-way combinations of categories from one-way combinations unless you make the very strong assumption that your factors are independent.

You can calculate two-way and three-way combinations from raw data that take the form sales, age, name.

Even more importantly, if your data are sales data, then you can't infer probability that people will buy a candy bar. Everything in your dataset refers to sales.

You might as well try to infer probability of church attendance just from counts of people in church.

Or take another example: Suppose today I had three cups of coffee. What is the probability that if I drink, then my drink will be coffee? You can't work that out without knowing what other drinks I had today.

Comment: Is there some purely numerical/computational way I could try without making any extra assumptions?

Comment: See revised answer above for extra details.